# ChromeDriver support issue

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I updated my Chrome Browser and installed the latest ChromeDriver version. Somehow I now gut the following erreor:

This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 96
Current browser version is 98.0.4758.81

How can I resolve this issue.

If possible answer as simple as possible because I am new to all of this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

for chromedriver of 98.0.4758.81, try using 98.0.4758.80. It shall work, and if not, please comment the error/issue. I have chrome 98.0.4758.81 and i just downloaded chromedriver 98.0.4758.80 recently (even myself hoping it will work)